# Almacenar valores no repetidos en un array de Javascript

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando hacer un ejercicio y ando atascado, ¿podrían darme algún consejo?

No quiero la respuesta, tan solo algún consejo que me ayude a replantearme el problema, pues tiene pinta de que voy por mal camino o no he interiorizado bien algunas cosas.

> Preguntar al usuario con un prompt la dimensión de un array, pedir valores numéricos con los que  rellenarlo. Es importante que los valores que se almacenen no se puedan repetir. Finalmente mostrar el array con los valores no repetidos.

No entiendo el motivo por que aunque meto valores repetidos ignora el `if (listado[i] == numero)...` y lo almacena todo.

```
var dimension = parseInt(prompt("Introduce una dimension para el array", ""));
console.log("la dimensión del array es: " + dimension);
var listado = new Array(dimension);
var repetido = false;
const rellenarArray = () => {
  console.log("el listado es: " + listado);
  for (let i = 0; i < listado.length; i++) {
    var numero = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un numero para el array", ""));
    console.log("ha introducido usted el: " + numero + " en el listado");
    console.log("el listado es: " + listado);
    if (listado[i] == numero) {
      console.log("Se sepite un número");
      repetido = true;
      //break;
      do {
        numero = parseInt(prompt("Un número que no se repite, please", ""));
      } while (repetido == true);
    } else {
      repetido = false;
      console.log("Repetido es igual a false");
      console.log("No se repite nada");
      listado[i] = numero;
    }
  }
  console.log("el listado es: " + listado);
};
rellenarArray();
```

Comment: porque jamas lo asignas.... solo validas si `listado[i]` que en ese momento es `undefined` es igual a `numero` debes replantear tu logica

Answer (score 0):

Agregué una función adicional para facilitar el proceso de validación de un número repetido.

```js
const dimension = parseInt(prompt('Introduce una dimension para el array', ''));
console.log('la dimensión del array es: ' + dimension);
const listado = new Array(dimension);
const repetido = numero => listado.includes(numero);
console.log('el listado es: ' + listado);
const rellenarArray = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < listado.length; i++) {
    let numero = parseInt(prompt('Introduce un numero para el array', ''));

    if (repetido(numero)) {
      do {
        numero = parseInt(prompt('Un número que no se repita, please', ''));
      } while (repetido(numero));
    }

    console.log('ha introducido usted el: ' + numero + ' en el listado');
    listado[i] = numero;
    console.log('el listado es: ' + listado);
  }
};

rellenarArray();
console.log('el listado es: ' + listado);
```